# How to validate header parameters with Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, http-headers, sinatra, http-status-code-404

I'm working on a simple API with Sinatra and I have a route like this one:

```
get '/api/v1/invoice/:biller', :provides => [:json] do
   respond_with invoice( request )
end
```

It works like a charm when I don't send any header params, but when I send:

- Accept
- Content-Type

Then I got a `404 Not Found` error and the classic Sinatra error *'Sinatra doesn't know this ditty'*.

How can I validate specific header params on Sinatra?

**Edit**

This is the actual header (Accept) with a curl example:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.tpago.billpayment+json" -X GET "http://localhost:3540/api/v1/invoice/5947647"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you edit to add the actual headers you used, with their value. Or even better, a `curl` command line or similar to show how you are sending them. You shouldn't need to set `Content-Type` for a GET request, there is no content

Comment: I added the curl line! Thanks!

Comment: Does `curl -H "Accept: application/json"` work? I'm not sure Sintra's `:provides` condition knows about your media type . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change your request to:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET "http://localhost:3540/api/v1/invoice/5947647"
```

It will work as Neil suggest or if you modify your Sinatra app to:

```
configure do
  # include new mime type
  mime_type :tpago, 'application/vnd.tpago.billpayment'
end

# add into provide options
get '/api/v1/invoice/:biller', :provides => [:tpago,:json] do
   respond_with invoice( request )
end
```

Now, the following request will work:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.tpago.billpayment" -X GET "http://localhost:3540/api/v1/invoice/5947647"
```

I am not totally sure, but I think "+" sign doesn't work on `Accept` header. I didn't find any reference about it on w3 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks tlewin!

I applied your solution but then I discovered an issue with 'respond_with'. It was always returning a `408 Not Acceptable` so I went to the [Sinatra's documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/respond_with.html), so I used a respond_to:

```
get '/api/v1/invoice/:biller', :provides => [:tpago,:json] do
  result = invoice( request )
  respond_to do |f|
    f.on('application/vnd.tpago.billpayment+json') { result.to_json }
  end
end
```

And now it's working! :D

Thank you again!