# Idiomatic REST API versioning in Padrino app

Tags: ruby, rest, versioning, padrino

I am writing a `Padrino` app which will expose a few services via `REST` apis. I need to version the apis. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20775241/341008) answer which explains how to version an api such that the version is embedded in the uri. I would rather put my version info in the `Accept` header or some other HTTP header (let's not go into the whole embed-in-uri vs put-in-header debate for now). Is there an idiomatic way of implementing this in a `Padrino` controller? I would like to avoid littering version checks in all my routes. Is there any way I can put the check in a central place (DRY) or - better still - let `Padrino` take care of this for me with some magical directives?

Comment: I've been searching for the same thing a time ago. Have you check body parameters ? You can join this with a `before` filter that will dispatch your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement (ofc, w/o 'v1' in url) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003755/how-to-validate-header-parameters-with-sinatra).
Also found [that](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sinatrarb/mwAcT0RAYv0/aMC5aceLxLAJ). It should work since Padrino is the little bro of Sinatra.

Can't test for the moment. Please keep me aware !